# The Solve command is not able to find a solution of a system

Tags: equation-solving

I have a system with large rational numbers

```
sys={(142026663022779801640862637033742469272513756343674009890371499798816876769876965545121897599491738521436592262054999648071342299861810748989572513728634630717016058897008831414235275432*g1 + 21171900606046238361544026615144053784350537920098175497547687830696981686030404032027650671262562068558744990132289142478934455861785504514076181578190600618464528919200124782020736875033*γ1)*Conjugate[β1] == 6436513541041198356271643345779156101023601026407724291671550*(2474789885588676211793096785031242493851860826974087460503518648620725282567490608470313795507764614309172508562495193356984*g1 - 61184219969401121855906169022784781800621986886069986699506809209093668406099078509361539710511457265215747293069201531246831*γ1)*Conjugate[β2], (528139678412670057220006754446875727100994948547689624837269611734407757536820475507216721884245978169231006181195855053150130286716814728311092210909299998126006330566087263036836441832*g1 - 1502993113034337311655577870642455296753979427380693779782815006458622835959382287875530279704117704731308495839118169876347604541293506735192517945564307246208704782932204875599468510434367*γ1)*Conjugate[β1] == 6436513541041198356271643345779156101023601026407724291671550*(610211153275127153582633918659470715881571601543768882047423987864893318814899642374650863280400872689074199547017554641482104*g1 + 5693816777530371176226625041728980995841421179168535004827833759635199995083558741566080746874540004076226152261737186968995129*γ1)*Conjugate[β2], (342972725331571192886683718581034848898999895626541390664089427332871316756666979185796820308587592709270765912701562927637149292247940538958395703082156724953230844174489017602520192028*g1 + 204166199697502277459012504841078965805130481601793855058420006462840289082850314761918292176431610295839178755732454519781973986695984530473248268979783335153276562543288438155110680487957*γ1)*Conjugate[β1] + 247558213116969167548909359453044465423984654861835549679675*(1356529543367696150889927078870086541606546662662616065695164319461967745306011535672052346785706113729304635234949781086709744*g1 + 18737375699704917796581334595258801217249070676548738505764127709682072909990818794841581704534880294527711183847502977683981789*γ1)*Conjugate[β2] == 0, 2*(458669679822153584080632527659004722611426770202628119335560975322712910132004081804232470858332381773355042582816098085394666733316303557988457535698252925*g1 - 59564474131008010120819841087652055068175127056198132460951063522121978452492935115916244414068161335411248999291301714287730192990601581919911717046533536293*γ1)*Conjugate[β1] == 551448937037134689473739473197094276950226338594606569*(4722754188068641689408354294984792970159060315814727525751813441126774724311101148081185129095750641075*g1 - 105509923726213008190865219349509553950500316531018003542306899125964432250847506443576515475737593657747*γ1)*Conjugate[β2] , (39520155242609566158873068881357514918643764261610578362321537476818145566711889019362195640985994622200126693329567560554088472716451504750025425792404847750*g1 + 690522100199363032642655648284063115217211308260121315736232335687084946606870465421534710755220285286756906641676266272950150353101216023030112072012310941386*γ1)*Conjugate[β1] == 551448937037134689473739473197094276950226338594606569*(5943470749669240728390642007965751324707472749287879538807491113409005864753436575029365068754221386125*g1 + 656859037808874010936435597204969612458856710899901030070726394376053825142669021308968004003569808075347*γ1)*Conjugate[β2], 2*(28354757294348724465492577156398134822690826803684095992745321262166116178183492790736154193865248485849132007675350440726220023095292074521557961179689114325*g1 + 903459484464137949466456817960097069147460945646490415618747890344037000481677405229187841426993044555165835882121809116399863865199126202521760368457490462283*γ1)*Conjugate[β1] + 22609406418522522268423318401080865354959279882378869329*(467158319312523130423902436869712112753547049341315861922299905117211977468137678942488085434464190325*g1 - 40772372510191740131967148208267419670866572989861027038310315783033734971279294985224824097598056213877*γ1)*Conjugate[β2] == 0, 17*(7287054838836733006947201452619931315649025869880364068149014642304743824281537951781697959755010559079754916996138371157709428689665857236359099859500081*g1 + 27544545270805118149133148640662554768074049227125802560539217812186182240594222169320634433072317294222312842748040806567975848870514874966179474220119370*γ1)*Conjugate[β1] + 1468088181346693525831507066074678560572946440310*(7585797394595484668442084995983673595590544923949894627521498575587848578345620593700887104253328847565003*g1 - 209200157367874622356284722908167354643873059668595375531681453482028099827748997451602335915465121769611278*γ1)*Conjugate[β2] == 0, (50284060333460269826498953308309207072074377771568797357657767153725423082268128419387041631988259930689275107768164928576401969050112274313602466544116977*g1 + 190185071882915164107352617125995824583603202377399599709942209362506230456280421029137742801548345836659510219540192565260292032152380737442145408889804770*γ1)*Conjugate[β1] + 24957499082893789939135620123269535529740089485270*(181132928340439045649049925850915547044823627942752857137185222432787305289889121074310653955466552931171*g1 - 4997407272569140638491886956144572431603766116002880806374729460153543650240331478092218394881861638136254*γ1)*Conjugate[β2] == 0, (573810329276619861685689754970994982598469736248007199871300209069254645796760834270383597595782216461287342921561055728392491148667619509822959423660139241*g1 + 2189330362693108125768064909879913666578484309540951126437383493457299549417771944806840170985897619700508308457192051743159391548475111841906411004448812410*γ1)*Conjugate[β1] + 16148969994813628784146577726821464166302410843410*(3196096622148723462203937931768851402167308047591511253622094675580738933859853669582681663678679745375721*g1 - 88729443042641999767140529745623620193478209941118054782266655234401470932398115830517245906998427231544954*γ1)*Conjugate[β2] == 0}
```

When solving this system, Mathematica is not able to find the full set of solutions. For example, with Mathematica 12.0 I get

```
Solve[sys]
(*Output: {{g1->0,γ1->0}} *)
```

If instead I enforce `g1=γ1` I get

```
Solve[sys /. g1 -> γ1]
(*Output: {{γ1->0},{β1->0,β2->0}} *)
```

So, Mathematica is missing the solution `{β1->0,β2->0}`. I can get more solutions if I do restrict to real values for the unkowns

```
Solve[sys/.Conjugate[a_]->a]
(*Output:{{g1->0,γ1->0},{β1->0,β2->0},{g1->0,β1->0,γ1->0}} *)
```

Why there is this mismatch? Mathematica is not even telling me the set of solutions is not complete.

Comment: Try using Reduce instead of Solve.

Comment: Thanks. But what's the problem with `Solve`?

Comment: Solve allows non-equivalent transforms, Reduce doesn't. All that is described in the documentation to the commands.